# subsonic bug? ExpressionVisitor linq

Tags: c#, subsonic3

I have a problem with this subsonic3.0.0.4 find statement:

```
 IList<Market> marketlist = marketlRep.Find<Market>(
     type => type.MarketType == Convert.Int32(MarketType)).
     OrderBy(type => type.DisplayOrder).ToList();
```

There are four the number of data in the database, but the list returned is empty

Use the following form, you can return the correct data.

```
 var mtype = Convert.ToInt32(marketType);
 IList<Market> marketlist = marketlRep.Find<Market>(
     type => type.MarketType == mtype).
     OrderBy(type => type.DisplayOrder).ToList();
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Dunno if it is a typo, but `marketType` has different capitalization in your examples.

Comment: Thanks, I have resolved, is indeed a BUG
SubSonic.Core\Extensions\QueryVisitor.cs
if(obj != null)
{
......
}
else
{
   //2010-9-2 丁富升修改 改正不能带转换函数的问题。
   return base.VisitMethodCall(methodCallExpression);
}